# angularjs ui-grid celltemplate to show html styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have content that i would like to render on the cell as html template,
i.e. when the tags are shown it should display as font color red.

is it possible using ui-grid

```
<font color="red"> Record is not processed </font> in Indicator section by association with failed record in CORE section.206
```

Comment: did you try the solution mentioned here - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3171

Comment: i haven't but sounds like good option